# Is it possible to make gameobjects spread to formations using Reynolds' Group Separation Behaviour?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, twitch

In a Unity C# project involving human cells, I want to achieve an effect whereby a group of cells spread out to form a crescent-like formation like so:
[Desired formation of cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnoY0.jpg). (Sorry for the inconvenience, I'm currently a new user to this website).

I tried to adopt [Conrad Parker's set-up in Java](http://www.vergenet.net/~conrad/boids/pseudocode.html) of Reynolds' group steering behaviour, specifically the Group Separation, then I modified the weighting of x and y axis of the separation in an attempt to get that crescent-like formation.

```
//Conrad Parker's setup in Java
PROCEDURE rule2(boid bJ)

    Vector c = 0;

    FOR EACH BOID b
        IF b != bJ THEN
            IF |b.position - bJ.position| < 100 THEN
                c = c - (b.position - bJ.position)
            END IF
        END IF
    END

    RETURN c

END PROCEDURE

//My adoption of Conrad Parker's setup without modification

    Vector2 Steering = new Vector2(0f,0f);
    foreach(GameObject GO in _SameGOType)
    {
        if(GO != _Agent)
        {
            Vector2 difference = new Vector2(GO.transform.position.x - _Agent.transform.position.x, GO.transform.position.y - _Agent.transform.position.y);
            float distance = difference.magnitude;
            if(distance <= 1f)
            {
                Steering.x -= difference.x;
                Steering.y -= difference.y;
            } 
        }
    }
    return Steering;

//My adoption with modification in an attempt to achieve the formation

    Vector2 Steering = new Vector2(0f,0f);
    foreach(GameObject GO in _SameGOType)
    {
        if(GO != _Agent)
        {
            Vector2 difference = new Vector2(GO.transform.position.x - _Agent.transform.position.x, GO.transform.position.y - _Agent.transform.position.y);
            float distance = Mathf.Sqrt(0.5f * Mathf.Pow(difference.x,2f) + 1.8f * Mathf.Pow(difference.y,2f));//difference.magnitude;//Mathf.Sqrt(1f * Mathf.Pow(difference.x,2f) + Mathf.Pow(difference.y,2f));
            if(distance <= 1f)
            {
                Steering.x -= difference.x;
                Steering.y -= difference.y;
            } 
        }
    }
    return Steering;
```

The attempt only resulted in a behaviour that create a rectangular-like formation. (I can provide a link to my attempt of the formation, if you need !)

Additionally, the cells started to twitch as it get closer to it's position and stop when it reached. So I'm curious as to is my idea of using Group Separation Behaviour to attain the desired crescent-like formation is fundamentally wrong or I simply taken a wrong approach of using it ?

Thank you for reading my question !